# Non-closed Neeman forcing

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

This question is something of a follow-up to this one:
[Iterating Neeman's forcing](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374224/iterating-neemans-forcing)

It regards the work of Itay Neeman, MR3201836.

Neeman formulates his two-type models forcing seemingly in greater generality than is actually used.  He defines what it means for a quadruple $\kappa,\lambda,\mathcal S,\mathcal T$ to be *appropriate* for a transitive structure $K$ satisfying enough ZFC, and defines the sequences of models in $\mathcal S \cup \mathcal T$ that make up the conditions of his forcing.  Let me highlight the key things relevant to my question:

1. The sequences have length less than $\kappa$.
2. The models in $\mathcal T$ are assumed to be ${<}\kappa$-closed.  But in practice they are often assumed to be $|M|$-closed for every $M \in \mathcal S$, which is usually ${\leq} \kappa$-closed.  The exception is when they are assumed internally club via $\mathcal S$-type models.
3. The models in $\mathcal S$ are assumed to contain $\kappa$ but *not* to be ${<}\kappa$-closed.  However, they can be, and Neeman notes that if they are, then the whole forcing is ${<}\kappa$-closed.  But Neeman takes some effort to show that the main properties of the forcing hold without this assumption.

Now, why does he go to such pains?  **Question**:  Are there any examples in the literature, or in your own unpublished notes, of such forcing where $\kappa>\omega$, the models in $\mathcal S$ are *not* $\kappa$-closed, and we can show that $\kappa$ is preserved?

Comment: Have you tried asking Itay? I'm very out of touch with set theory now, but I never heard a set-theorist other than Itay say that they understand this stuff.